# What is the difference between <% and <%i in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Sometimes I see codes come with "i", and sometimes without it. What is the difference between `<% %>` and `<%i %>`?

Comment: Show some examples, fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no such char sequence in
JSR-000245 JavaServerTM Pages 2.3 Maintenance Release 2 for Evaluation

Only:
Directive elements have a syntax of the form <%@ directive...%> .

There are three language-based types of scripting elements: declarations,
scriptlets, and expressions. Declarations follow the syntax <%! ... %>. Script-
lets follow the syntax <% ... %> . Expressions follow the syntax <%= ... %> .

Maybe you saw "**!**" not "**i**" character?

Where did you saw it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean <%! instead of <%i ?
<%! %> is a JSP declaration and is used to declare variables and methods.

A link that might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html